# Visual Studio 2010: Multiple requests debugging at the same time (Annoying!)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

**The setup**

I have an MVC application that's making AJAX requests into my controller.  The javascript is making more than one such request.

On my controller that gets called, I have a break point.

**The annoyance**

When I want to debug that controller action method, I hit my breakpoint, press F10 to continue on, but then the second request comes in and I hit the breakpoint again!  I've now got two requests flowing through my code, and pressing F10 steps between the two, making the debugging nearly impossible as the current line jumps up and down, between files, etc without any consistent flow as it's tracking more than one request in the current debugging session!

**My question**

Can I tell a single request to just... go away... without affecting the other one?  I've tried F5ing just one request, but that makes both continue, not just the current one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could disable the breakpoint immediately after its first hit (Ctrl-F9, or right click on the breakpoint and click disable - this is different from removing the breakpoint).

You can also "Freeze" a thread in the threads window (right click on the thread and click "Freeze" - use "Thaw" to reverse this).

Comment: The immediate-disable idea didn't work.  Also, it's a pain to freeze the threads because there's a bagillion of them in my app, but thankfully it shows which ones are actually executing the code I care about.  Thanks for that pointer.

Comment: @Adam There are ways to automatically freeze all of them at once, see this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201849/freeze-all-threads-on-breakpoint-in-vs2010/6556576#6556576