# Getting data about an anonymous exception during debug session

Tags: c++, visual-studio

So, here's the problem I have.

```
void * something = ???;
void (*fun)(void*) = ???;

try
{
    fun(something);
}
catch (...)
{
    assert(false);
}
```

I've been tasked with establishing why the assert is getting fired.  Unfortunately I don't get to change the above code.  Furthermore this is in a multi-threaded environment and it's during shutdown of the program.  The part that does the try/catch is unlocked quite purposefully in the real world code.  When I try to step through the program it suddenly just disappears on me...I can't even step TO the right fun() call, let alone into it.

My only recourse seems to be to put a breakpoint in the catch(...) and examine whatever is there.  Unfortunately this tells me nothing as I don't know what fun really is nor what something is.

My only hope at this point is that I can somehow talk the Visual Studio debugger into telling me what `...` is and I'd be overjoyed if I could find out where it was thrown.  It's not in the auto list at least...might it be elsewhere?  Is there any way for me to make progress here or am I screwed?  I feel screwed...

====

Update:  There was an external program killing mine when it didn't shut down in time.  That's why stepping made it disappear.  Had nothing to do with threads.

Once I realized that I was able to turn on exceptions as suggested.  Unfortunately there was no place that throws one...it was an access violation.  The function being stored gets pounded somehow.

Comment: Are you stepping over an optimized binary? If so, it may be simpler to understand what's going on having a look at the disassembly for this section of code...

Comment: @MatteoItalia - no, it's all debug built.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use Visual Studio functionality that breaks execution when an exception is thrown. Go to Visual Studio main menu Debug -> Exceptions and tick all exceptions.

This way visual studio will stop when your exception is thrown and you will know what it was.

Comment: can it help you if you freeze the other threads as in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201849/freeze-all-threads-on-breakpoint-in-vs2010

Comment: Probably!  I bet that would help a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Can you just go to menu: **Debug|Exceptions** and mark the exceptions that you suspect is thrown ?
If you can step/attach to a running program that should be possible. This will cause the debugger to break when a specific exception(s) are thrown.

I usually mark the whole subtree '**Win32 Exceptions**' in the Debug|Exceptions dialog box. I assume the your program does not throw and silently ignore other (Win32) exceptions (in this case you would have a lot of 'false' alarms).

I hope that helps.